# Distributed Database Access in aws cloud front

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have MYSQL Database in AWS RDS and Web Application in Mumbai Region. I want to access the web application from the USA with good latency/speed. I have used AWS CloudFront still the application is very slow.

Any Suggestions.
Best,
Syed

AWS CloudFront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard, it is recommended to keep databases and apps should be in the same regions(eventually can try to keep in the same zone) from the majority of end-user belongs to

As of now, you can create a cross-region replica but you need to be ready for replica lag and data transfer charges. In the long term, plan to move your setup to N.Virgania or any other USA region.

Answer (score 1):

How about a cross-region read replica of your MySQL database in the USA? If the majority of your database operations are read rather than write, this will give you a significant improvement in response time.